# Typescript: How type a function using generic type in this case?

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

I have this type definition

```
type FuncType<T> = (value: T) => T
```

I want to implement a function using this type that would look like:

```
const myFunc: FuncType<T> = (value) => value;
```

and use it as follows:

```
const a: string = myFunc<string>('a');
const b: number = myFunc<number>(2);
```

But, of course, the previous line `const myFunc: FuncType<T> = (value) => value;` doesn't have a valid syntax.

**How should it be written ?**

---

**Note**:
I found a workaround using an intermediate function but it would be nice to avoid this useless currying *(that I cannot use anyway in my real use case because it's related to react hook and react hooks doesn't tolerate currying)*:

```
const myFunc = <T>(): FuncType<T> => (value) => value;
const a: string = myFunc<string>()('a');
const b: number = myFunc<number>()(2);
```

---

**Why do I need to use this type alias and cannot directly write ?**

```
const myFunc = <T>(value: T): T => value;
```

Because in my real use case, the type definition of my function is not that simple.

It looks like something like that:

```
interface FuncType<T> {
  (args: {arg1: T}): {res1: T}
  (args: {arg1: T, arg2: T}): {res1: T, res2: T}
}
```

Comment: Do you really need the type alias? Maybe you could just `function myFunc<T>(value: T) : T { return value; }`

Comment: @AlekseyL. I updated my question to answer to yours.

Comment: The question is: are you using the type in multiple places? If yes, please show the use case. Otherwise my suggestion is still valid - add as many overloads as needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far I don't see a use case for `FuncType` being a generic type alias to a concrete overloaded function.  Could you instead make it a *concrete* type alias to a *generic* overloaded function?  Like this:

```
interface FuncType {
  <T>(args: { arg1: T }): { res1: T }
  <T>(args: { arg1: T, arg2: T }): { res1: T, res2: T }
}
```

Then `FuncType` will always refer to something that accepts any `T`, and you can use it the way you wanted:

```
const myFunc: FuncType =
  (value: { arg1: any, arg2?: any }) => ({ res1: value.arg1, res2: value.arg2 });

const a = myFunc<string>({ arg1: "" }); // { res1: string; }
const b = myFunc<number>({ arg1: 1, arg2: 2 }); // { res1: number; res2: number; }
```

Hopefully that meets your needs.  Good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=10&pc=83#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIFcQICoE8AOKA3gLABQyyAPNgHwAUcUA5gM4BcyRyTzAjJ2zIAvgEpO3KBFYDkQ4eUo0GvDlx4tZ2ADQbmAJkEjx6qTMG6zhuSPIKy5BAHsQrMMgC2uDFk4+cBCgAvIrI9ABucAA26BASerJwILi6vPoA-JxJuMbIQbRhktKykTEQAHS8fJbS1qWxlSz6xgDc5I4ubjx5nt6YCFRuUKDMDNxVnABEk63IAPRzpsWcQyMttmTOru4ARj1e-lQg6B470GMJnNV61s1i6wtL5sjHp9DrVpyvZ1DrwkA)

Answer (score 0):

To sum up, simply change from

```
type FuncType<T> = (value: T) => T
```

to

```
type FuncType = <T>(value: T) => T
```